# Prove $\lim_{x\to ∞} \frac{x - \sin(x+1)}{3x+9} = \frac{1}{3}$

Tags: calculus

**Prove**: $$\lim_{x\to ∞} \frac{x - \sin(x+1)}{3x+9} = \frac{1}{3}$$

**Scratch work**: I want,

$$\epsilon > |\frac{x-\sin(x+1)}{3x+9} - \frac{1}{3}|$$
$$=|\frac{-3\sin(x+1)-9}{9x+27}|$$
$$=\frac{-3\sin(x+1)-9}{9x+27} \text{ assuming }x>0$$

**Rearranging the inequality:**

$$\epsilon > \frac{-3\sin(x+1)-9}{9x+27}$$
$$(9x+27)\epsilon > -3\sin(x+1)-9$$
$$9x\epsilon+27\epsilon > -3\sin(x+1)-9$$
$$9x\epsilon > -3\sin(x+1)-9-27\epsilon$$
$$x > \frac{-3\sin(x+1)-9-27\epsilon}{9\epsilon}$$

At this point of the scratch work, I'm lost as to what to do with the $\sin(x+1)$ and I'm stuck with continuing on with the actual proof. I was wondering if anyone can help me with what should be done next.

Comment: Have you heard of the squeeze theorem? Hint: $-1 \leq \sin(x)|\leq 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More simple:
as $|\sin(.)|\leq 1$, $$
\frac{x-1}{3x + 9}\leq f(x)
\leq \frac{x+1}{3x + 9}
$$
and both left and right members goes to $\frac13$, so there is a $A$ such as:

$$
x\ge 3\Rightarrow \max (\left|\frac{x-1}{3x + 9}-\frac 13\right|, \left|\frac{x+1}{3x + 9}-\frac 13\right|) \leq \epsilon
\\
\Rightarrow \left|f(x) - \frac 13
\right|\leq \epsilon
$$

Answer (score 1):

You're done. $\epsilon$ is a fixed number and $|\sin(x+1)|\leq 1$ so the right hand side has a fixed maximum value (when $\sin(x+1)=-1$ in this case). Then for all $x$ greater than that value, the difference is less than $\epsilon$.